# XML DTD Specify a cdata/text pattern for attribute

Tags: xml, dtd

Is there a way, in a DTD, to specify a "pattern" for a given attribute.

Example: I want to have an attribute called "*position*" which is a string of the form **"X,Y"**.

I would like to have something in my DTD similar to:

```
<!ATTLIST MyElement 
    myattribute "*,*"
>
```

*(I know, for this example two attributes X and Y would certainly be better, but that's just to highlight what I want to do)*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a pattern using DTD. You could do it using a schema though:

```
  <xs:element name="MyElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="myattribute" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[^,]+,[^,]+"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The `value` in `xs:pattern` is a regular expression.

Comment: Great thanks. I think I may switch from DTD to schema so, seems to be more handy.